# Trailing Slashes :: reduce to only one single slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to reduce multiple trailing slashes into one single trailing slash, but not remove multiple slashes inside the url-string. I tried this one, but it kicks the slashes inside:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

---

```
https://xy.com/hh////hhh//
```

should be directed to:

```
https://xy.com/hh////hhh/
```

Comment: Do you want to remove one slash in the end of URL?

Comment: I want to remove all slashes at the end of the string except one single  slash. In this example it should remove one slash.

Comment: [Here you go](https://regex101.com/r/kV0tB2/4)

Comment: Thank you - the regex works fine, but the Redirect is not correct. Perhaps there is a Problem in the combination of Redirects and rewrites in the htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule to convert **multiple trailing `/` into a single trailing `/`**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*?)/{2,}(\?.*)?\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule /$ %1/ [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you! This kicks also slashes inside the string.

Comment: I think you have to edit your pattern, [as OP said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548960/trailing-slashes-reduce-to-only-one-single-slash?noredirect=1#comment60700637_36548960), he just want one slash in the end of URL. But your pattern [just removes one slash in the end of URL](https://regex101.com/r/kV0tB2/5).

Comment: Don't try to test it on rege101 as it cannot be tested online. @merti: Please try my updated rule after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Thanks anubhava! I don´t get an error but it leaves the slashes. My Cache is deactivated - i think the Problem is the combination of rewrites.

Comment: I think it works after sorting commands in the htaccess. Thank you very much anabhava!

Answer (score 0):

Will it help?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*[^/])/*$
RewriteRule . %1/ [R=301,L]
```